# Divide variables to int

Tags: c#

Basically what I need to know:

I make a variable number, it's value is let's say 1-100.
Then I make another variable number. I need to know if it's possible to make sure that I can divide number 2 by number 1.

For example: `20 / 5 = 4`

The problem is that I want the answer to be an int. So nothing after the comma. I only want two numbers like `20/5, 12/4, 56/8` and not `10/7,13/3` etc.
So not like this:

`21 / 5 = 4,2`

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `21 / 5` at all? If so show your code. Do you want to round or to truncate?

Comment: `int / int` is performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) which always disregards fractional part which is _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: Are you looking for the [modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)? As in `if (x % y != 0) { /* integer division wont be "exact" */ }`?

Comment: I don't really know what that percentage does, but if that means there won't be a remainder then yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Please read through the linked MSDN entry. Modulus get's the remainder of an integer division. If that remainder is zero, you can divide without a reminder. Else, there would be a reminder.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I get it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both values are an `integer` and you divide them. Then it won't have anything after the comma.

So you are safe to use: `int d = x / y;` if `x, y` are integers.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int x  = rand.Next(1, 100);
int y  = rand.Next(1, 100);

int d = x / y;
```

> I just don't want it to do 10/7, only 10/5 100/20 5/5 30/3, and NOT 10/7 11/ 3 8/5

In this case you would need something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int x  = rand.Next(1, 100);
int y  = rand.Next(1, 100);
while (x % y != 0 && x != y)
{
    y = rand.Next(1, 100);
}

int d = x / y;
```

Comment: yes I know, but I want there to be no remainder. Because when I'd do int d = 10 / 7 The answer really is 1,4....

Comment: There won't be.. as it would always return an integer... which doesn't use comma's at all.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the real answer to be 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 etc. not just what the integer would return. So I want to make only sums which will have no remainder

Comment: I really think you need to be more clear..... so if we do `10/7` what is the result that YOU want? Did you even try my code? https://ideone.com/VD1XKR

Comment: I just don't want it to do 10/7, only 10/5 100/20 5/5 30/3, and NOT 10/7 11/ 3 8/5

Comment: In that case you would need something completely different. You would need... let me update my answer.

Comment: sorry for not being clear about what I want, I appreciate everyone's time though

Comment: See my other comment, I think you're looking for something like `while (x % y != 0) { x = rand.Next(1, 100); y = rand.Next(1, 100); }`

Comment: Added something like that too in my answer. Google `modulo` if you want to know what `%` does.

Comment: Yes thanks, this is exactly what I need, I'm sorry Corak I didn't see your comment in the first place. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if it's possible to make sure that I can divide number
>   2 by number 1.

You could simply generate your first number (call it `1`), then generate a second number, (call it `temp`). You would then generate another number (call it `2`) by doing `1 * temp`. This would allow that the second number is perfectly divisible by the first.

If you want to take the integral part of the division simply cast the numbers as integers and divide those. The division of two integer values will always yield another integer (that is, the remainder part will be omitted).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to check if the two numbers divide without a reminder and then perform the division the correct way is:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int x  = rnd.Next(1, 100);
int y  = rnd.Next(1, 100);

int i;
if(x % y == 0)
{
  i = x / y;
}
```